# How to convert boost::posix_time::ptime to OLE Automation Date (OADate)?

Tags: date, boost, time, posix, ole

I would like to convert a `boost::posix_time::ptime` to an `OLE Automation Date` (`OADate` for short).  The OADate is a `floating point` numerical representation of the date and time.

Please can someone explain & demonstrate (C++) how to achieve the conversion?

Comment: Reason for duplicate: _[The DATE date type, as well as the COleDateTime class, represents dates and times as a classic number line. The COleDateTime class contains several methods for manipulating DATE values, including conversion to and from other common date formats.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82ab7w69.aspx)_